# Php Date not working on the server

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

for some reason the Php date isn't working on the server.

Here is the function for displaying the tip of the day. I am using the codeigniter framework. In the function below i am trying to print the day of year ($doy). When i go to the url and try to access the tip function it shows a blank page. The day of year is not printed.

```
public function tip(){      

    $idCount = $this->db->query('SELECT Count(*) AS COUNT FROM clickmag_tip')->result();
    $total = $idCount[0]->COUNT; 

    $time = time();
    $doy = mdate('%z', $time);
    echo $doy;
    //$day_of_year = date('z',time());

    //$doyear = date("z") + 1; 
    //echo $doyear;

    $s = mktime(date("G") + 1); 
    print date("Y/m/d h:i:s a", $s);

    if($total > 0){
        $offset = $doy % $total ;
    }

    $data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_tip LIMIT 1 OFFSET '. $offset);
    header('Content-type: text/json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data->result());

}
```

What do you think is the problem? I talked to the server people but they also don't know.
How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
flush();

Add these code to start of your php page, and try loading.

Comment: Blank page may also result from some syntax errors in the page.

Comment: Also, there is no function `mdate()`

Comment: `echo $doy;` starts the output so you cannot send headers after that.

Comment: @JohnWatson - `mdate()` is a codeigniter function.

Comment: @ Krishnanunni - Thanks that was a real help. Could you please tell me what does these code does..?

Answer (score 1):

You must output all headers before outputting anything.

You have both:

`echo $doy;`

AND

`print date("Y/m/d h:i:s a", $s);`

Before

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

That is what's causing the blank page.